# MassTransit and Simple Injector

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, masstransit, simple-injector

I'm reviewing the [MassTransit Distributed Application Framework for .NET](http://masstransit-project.com/). According to the website [MassTransit has been built from the beginning with the concept of an IoC container being involved](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/containers.html) and provides support libraries for a handful of the more "mainstream" IoC Containers. There are (currently) NuGet packages available for Autofac, StructureMap, Castle Windsor, Ninject & Unity.

I have selected [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) as my IoC container of choice [for performance reasons](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) but I am unable to find an integration library adding support for Simple Injector to MassTransit.

Has anyone tried this, got it to work and have some code available to get me started?

Comment: There's no MassTransit integration library for Simple Injector that I know of.

Comment: There is a NuGet package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.SimpleInjector/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MassTransit, but after looking at [the configuration examples for the other containers](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/usage/containers/index.html), this is what I came up with:

```cs
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new Container();

    var consumers = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IConsumer),
        applicationAssemblies);

    foreach (Type consumer in consumers)
        container.Register(consumer);

    IServiceBus bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc => {
        //other configuration options

        sbc.Subscribe(subs => {
            foreach (var consumer in consumers)
                subs.Consumer(consumer);
        });
    });

    container.RegisterSingle<IServiceBus>(bus);

    container.Verify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. For the time being I have implemented a local publish/subscribe framework with SimpleInjector using RegisterManyForOpenGeneric\RegisterAll and GetAllInstances etc. I will review message distribution later in the project.