# MassTransit IoC implementation with SimpleInjector

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, ioc-container, simple-injector, masstransit

I have to use MassTransit on my WebApi project, but I can't find any sample of how to implement it with Simple Injector on a WebApi 2 (OWIN) application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have tried and where you are stuck? Are you getting an exception? Please post the strack trace as well.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221571/masstransit-and-simple-injector

Comment: There is actually a package for integrating with Simple Injector: https://nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.SimpleInjector, problem is, MassTransit shows samples about several containers except for SimpleInjector :( http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers. I'm just looking for a sample on how to properly use that library for MassTransit.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/new) would be a good place to ask about using that package.

Comment: yeah, sadly the author of that package didn't write documentation for the repo :(

Comment: @ChrisPatterson will you guys have any sample handy to share? I'm trying with some stuff but not really sure it's the right way. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use it, so not really sure how it's used. I use Autofac.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Do you know the original author of the package? Just to check if I can send him an email about it. Thanks.